# Trajectory following test with Autoware.Auto and LGSVL simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings!

I'm trying to run the trajectory following test on a Jetson AGX (Autoware.Auto installed from source + ROS Dashing) with the LGSVL simulator running on another machine. I see that in the `lgsvl_interface` node it is expected the odometry information from the vehicle in the format of `lgsvl_msgs::VehicleOdometry` messages. However, when I add the corresponding sensor in the `.json` file, LGSVL throws an error saying that that sensor is not currently supported.
To deal with this issue, in the `LgsvlInterface::on_odometry` method, I set the longitudinal velocity of the `nav_base` frame equal to the linear velocity of the `base_link` frame, Vx, (comming from the `/lgsvl/gnss_odom` topic). This is true assuming planar motion and because the rotation matrix between the two frames is the identity 3x3.

However, for the `front_wheel_angle_rad` field, I do not know where I can get the proper value, which is required by the controller node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373557/trajectory-following-test-with-autoware.auto-and-lgsvl-simulator/) by [guillermoherreraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/67958/guillermoherreraf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current release of LGSVL (2020.06) had an unfortunate oversight during release: They forgot to add support for the VehicleOdometry message in the ROS2 plugin. However, Autoware.Auto provides a custom version of LGSVL which uses the [Ros2NativeBridge](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/ros2nativebridge) developed by Robotec.ai instead of the LGSVL bridge and that plugin *does* support the VehicleOdometry message. To use this on your simulation machine, install `ade` [using these instructions](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-ade.html) and then follow the instructions [on our LGSVL Simulator](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html) page to launch the simulator from `ade`. I tried to build a one-line Docker command that would allow you to run the LGSVL sim that we provide stand-alone (without ADE) but the command that `ade` builds is *way* too complex to try to generate myself.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guillermoherreraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/67958/guillermoherreraf/) on 2021-03-09**:
Hello @Josh Whitley. Thanks for your answer. The machine where I'm running the LGSVL simulator is running on Windows 10. Will I be able to install `ade` there? I see in the [ADE](https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#requirements) website that the instructions are for Linux. Furthermore, will it be possible to have the simulator running within the `ade` environment in my Windows machine, talking to the Autoware.Auto stack installed in the AGX from source?

If not, as a workaround right now I'm taking the linear velocity of the `nav_base` frame equal to the linear velocity of the `base_link`. For the `front_wheel_angle` value, I'm taking the `steer_pct` from the `CanBusData` message, and I map it to the `[-0.331, 0.331]` range. What do you think about that?

**Comment by [guillermoherreraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/67958/guillermoherreraf/) on 2021-03-09**:
**update**: I installed ADE on a Linux machine, to be able to connect it to the AGX via ethernet. Running the simulator within ADE in the Linux machine, and the Autoware stack compiled from source in the AGX. When I enter the ade environment with `ade --rc .aderc-amd64-dashing-lgsvl start --update --enter`, and then running `/opt/lgsvl/simulator` from within the `ade environment` I get the message: `Found path: /opt/lgsvl/simulator`. However, when I open the web browser and input the IP address: `127.0.0.1:8080`, I get `Unable to connect`. Any idea why this is happening?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-03-09**:
@guillermoherreraf Thanks for the update. For your two questions:

1. Yes, mapping the SteerPct to the radian range of the tires should work fine.
2. What version of Autoware.Auto are you using? The 1.0.0 release or `master`?

**Comment by [guillermoherreraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/67958/guillermoherreraf/) on 2021-03-09**:
@Josh Whitley.
Regarding 1. I get some strange behavior when doing this. Sometimes the vehicle starts oscillating around the steering angle.
2. I installed Autoware.Auto from the `master` branch.
3. Any idea why the LGSVL simulator is not working from within the ADE container?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-03-19**:
Please open a seperate question for LGSVL not working in ADE. However be aware that we no longer support Dashing on `master` after the 1.0.0 release.